# How to add underscore character in joomla ck form field label

Tags: joomla

I used the latest version of ckfrom joomla plugin for my joomla 1.5 project. I have faced some problem when defining the filed names of my form. Its always validated with letter& numeric values & cant add the special characters (underscore). I need a field name called "first_name", but no way to define it. Please can anyone tel me anyway to add this kind of field name in ckform

Comment: have you tried contacting the developers of the extension?

Answer (score 0):

Please Replace with this code in `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` in

`administrator\components\com_ckforms\views\ckfield\tmpl\ckfield_tpl.php` on line 20